# Animate single item in RecyclerView on data change

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, listadapter

I have complex and generic RecyclerView design and List Adapter.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding: ViewDataBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, viewType, parent, false)
    return object : BaseViewHolder(binding) {
        override fun bindData(position: Int) {
            val model = getItem(position).data
            itemBinding.setVariable(BR.model, model)
            viewModel?.let {
                itemBinding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, it)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.run {
        bindData(position)
        if (itemBinding.hasPendingBindings()) {
            itemBinding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
}
```

It has RecyclerView inside RecyclerView as item and handle multi layout by itself. I update list and items with databinding adapters. When I need to update single item; I search all tree in LiveData list, modify value and post value updated list to LiveData again.

I want to update each view with animation(item inside of RecyclerView inside of RecyclerView) when it's value changed.

here is my update code;

```
@BindingAdapter("setTransactionBgAnimation")
fun View.setTransactionBgAnimation(ratio: Double?) {
    ratio?.let { value ->
        val colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
            this, "backgroundColor", getEvaluateColor(context, value), Color.WHITE
        )
        colorAnim.duration = 500
        colorAnim.repeatCount = 1
        colorAnim.start()

        val alphaAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            this, "alpha", 0.40f, 0.0f
        )
        alphaAnim.duration = 500
        alphaAnim.repeatCount = 1
        alphaAnim.start()
    }
}
```

When value updated; it has called from all views for each change.
I tried to give unique tag to view and check tag in binding adapter but it is not worked for me.

Comment: Create a class extending `DefaultItemAnimator` and override `animateChange`.

Comment: @ADM the problem is I don't use notifyitemchanged. I modify whole list and post value all list to ListAdapter through databinding and livedata. I believe it will result same

Comment: It will not . Try DiffUtils

Comment: ListAdapter uses DiffUtils by default. I will try DefaultItemAnimator anyway and update here, thanks for now.

Comment: @ADM DafaultItemAnimator's or SimpleItemAnimator's animation change method called by notifyItemChanged. with ListAdapter I only use submitList, so not worked

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question at first. So there is a `OnBindViewHoder` variant with payload which will get called when a item's property is changed you can handle it fro `DiffUtil`  so i think u should be using this variant to animate the views. animate view only if payload contains the change. Does this make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with not -so clean- way.
First of all; animation was called for every visible item's count for each row, I fix it by controlling with giving view `tag` with changing value and check that tag that is same with new value.
After first fix, only really changed item animated but it animates multiple times. It was causing because of `ObjectAnimator`'s `backgroundColor` animations. I have no idea why did I even change backgroundColor with animation. I remove it and multiple flickering animation fixed too.

For better understanding please see my code part

```
fun View.setTransactionBgAnimation(ratio: Double?) {
   if (tag != ratio.toString()) {
       ratio?.let { value ->
           setBackgroundColor(getEvaluateColor(context, value))
           val alphaAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
               this, "alpha", 0.40f, 0.0f
           )
           alphaAnim.duration = 500
           alphaAnim.start()
       }
       tag = ratio.toString()
   }
}
```